# Why the 'xargs' command do not work with figlet but works fine when i run it with 'ls' argument

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

For example:

1. ```
   find /usr/share/figlet/ -type f -name "*.flf" | xargs ls -l
   ```

   ```
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3369 Mar 31 17:54 /usr/share/figlet/Tombstone.flf
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7641 Mar 31 17:54 /usr/share/figlet/Train.flf
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8336 Mar 31 17:54 /usr/share/figlet/Trek.flf
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9363 Mar 31 17:54 /usr/share/figlet/Tubular.flf
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15484 Mar 31 17:54 /usr/share/figlet/Univers.flf
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6644 Mar 31 17:54 /usr/share/figlet/usaflag.flf
   ```
2. ```
   find /usr/share/figlet/ -type f -name "*.flf" | xargs figlet -f
   ```

The first command generates an output but the second one does not. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: (I don't know what `figlet` is, but...) Does `figlet -f` accept multiple pathname arguments? Because that's what you're giving it. What do you expect as output?

Comment: @Kusalananda `figlet` prints text as ASCII art. With `-f` you can specify the "font". It only accepts one argument.
@OP, you can just use the `-exec` flag of find for this with a `;` at the back.

Comment: `figlet` accepts more than one argument, but `-f` only takes one; I’m surprised the OP doesn’t get any output, because `figlet` should take the first file as the font, and everything else as the message to format — that’s what it does on my system.

Comment: With xargs, use the ‘-p’ flag to see what it's going to do and give you a chance to break out if it's not what you want, when you're testing.

Comment: Coder_H! Make sure and click on the checkmark below if the answer answered your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to attempt an answer:

```
find /usr/share/figlet/ -type f -name "*.flf" | xargs -n 1 figlet -f
```

This will run *one* figlet command with *one* file name, and another figlet command with another file name, and so on.

See for example the difference between

```
find /usr/share/figlet/ -type f -name "*.flf" | xargs -t ls -l
```

and

```
find /usr/share/figlet/ -type f -name "*.flf" | xargs -t -n 1 ls -l
```

(By the way, I always include ‘-r’ on xargs, which will prevent xargs from running if there's no input. Otherwise you get a confusing empty line.)